# Tracking clicks on Download button and save in database

Tags: laravel

I have simple `Download` button which is looks like this

```
<a download="{{ $thumb }}" href="{{ $thumb }}" class="btn btn-success">Download Image</a>
```

It is appearing on page when the image is found. The button is working perfectly and is downloading the image.

The page has simple input field which user can search the image and if image is found it's showed on page with button download.

I've made a function which saves each `string` which is searched and now I'm wondering if I can save also if button `Download` is clicked e.g. the image is downloaded.

Can someone show me an example? I'm using laravel 5.4 here. So maybe I need to pass to the controller click event?

Current controller function

```
public function getImage(Request $request)
{
    $url = get_curl_content_tx('http://example.com/api?url='.$request->input('url'));
    $items = json_decode($url, true);
    $thumb = $items['thumbnail_url'];

    $db_save = new Image();

    $ip = $request->ip();
    $ip = DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($ip);

    $db_save->url = $request->input('url');
    $db_save->ip = DB::raw("inet_aton($ip)");
    $db_save->save();   
    return view('getImage',compact('thumb'));
}
```

Comment: I believe you'll need to use js (trigger 'click' event) and an ajax request (send the image's name to a server's script that would add the data to your DB).

Comment: You mean to wrap the button in form maybe and to create function in my Controller to save +1 in database on click?

Comment: Sure. Or have the `href` go to a route that records something, then redirects to the file.

Comment: You'll need **DataBase** to store the number of clicks, a `JavaScript` function to hundle the click on the download button and then `Ajax` to send data to a `PHP` Script that Update the number of clicks field in the DB.

Comment: I've updated my current controller which saves the url input after user search the image. If I create new function for download this will be doubled because will need to update the record, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Make sure that the `href` is going to a route where you keep track of these records and you can pass on the specific image to update the Record Model of the Image model itself if the counter is there? Something like this:

```
public function TrackDownload(Image $image){
    $imageRecord = Record::where('image_id', '=', $image->id); 

    $imageRecord->update([
        'download_counter' => $imageRecord->download_counter + 1; 
    ]);

    return redirect()->route(); 
}
```

Comment: But I don't know the ID yet. It's getting saved in DB once the image is returned because it's came from api. I've updated my question with the function